# Binding results in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

In the code below if I try to fetch results after two successive executions with different sets of parameters, it shows the same result set(the first one twice), instead of showing both the results with different parameters. What should I do? Also, in the PHP manual $sqli->bind_results() is put after $sqli->execute(), is it always mandatory or is it valid also to put $sqli->bind_results() before $sqli->execute() ?

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

  /*check connection*/
  if(mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    printf("connection failed: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  /*create prapared statement*/

  $sqli = $mysqli->prepare("select post_id from posts where id=?"); 

  /*bind params*/
  $sqli->bind_param('i',$id);


  /*set params*/
  $id =1;

  /*execute prapared statement*/
  $sqli->execute();

  /*bind results*/
  $sqli->bind_result($post_id);

  while($sqli->fetch())
  {
    echo ' '.$post_id;

  }

  echo '<br/>fetch new record<br/>';

  /*set params*/
  $id =2;

  /*execute prapared statement*/
  $sqli->execute();


  while($sqli->fetch())
  {
    echo ' '.$post_id;

  }
```

Executing in loops:*****

Scene1: calling bind_result($post_id) repeatedly

> ```
> <?php
>   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
>
>   /*check connection*/
>   if(mysqli_connect_errno())
>   {
>     printf("connection failed: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
>     exit();
>   }
>
>   /*create prapared statement*/
>
>   $sqli = $mysqli->prepare("select post_id from posts where id=?"); 
>
>   /*bind params*/
>   $sqli->bind_param('i',$id);
>
>   for($x=0;$x<1000;$x++)
>   {
>
>     $id =$x;
>
>
>     $sqli->execute();
>
>     /*****bind results*****/
>
>     $sqli->bind_result($post_id);
>
>     while($sqli->fetch())
>     {
>       echo ' '.$post_id;
>
>     }
>   }
> ?>
> ```

Scene2: calling bind_result($post_id) once

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

  /*check connection*/
  if(mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    printf("connection failed: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  /*create prapared statement*/

  $sqli = $mysqli->prepare("select post_id from posts where id=?"); 

  /*bind params*/
  $sqli->bind_param('i',$id);

  /*****bind results*****/

  $sqli->bind_result($post_id);

  for($x=0;$x<1000;$x++)
  {

    $id =$x;


    $sqli->execute();


    while($sqli->fetch())
    {
      echo ' '.$post_id;

    }
  }
?>
```

Now,as par PHP manual bind_result() should be used after execute(),but as shown in the scene1 above this will call "bind_result()" repeatedly whereas in scene2 it is called just once and still it is doing well. Which approach is better? Is scen2 valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to run `bind_result` **after each** `execute`.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)...

> Note that all columns must be bound after `mysqli_stmt_execute()` and prior to calling `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`.

So, you're only missing the second (required) call to `bind_result`...

```
$id = 2;
$sqli->execute();
$sqli->bind_result($post_id);
```

Comment: Thank you @phil , but I have a question yet: it is ok to bind it for the second time as you mentioned in your answer. But what if I execute it within a loop and there needs to bind it as many times as the loop continues, then doesn't it imply calling the bind_result() function again and again..any alternative to this problem?

Comment: @ParveezAhmed each time you call execute, a new result object is loaded internally. Therefore, you need to re-bind your result variables.